# Support for vertical wrapped text with Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges in Mono

Tags: c#, text, graphics, mono

For Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges, is it possible to measure vertically wrapped text in a CJK font?

Here is what I tried:

```
    static public System.Drawing.RectangleF MeasureDisplayString(Graphics graphics, string text, Font font) 
    { 
        System.Drawing.StringFormat format = new System.Drawing.StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic); 
        format.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft; 
        format.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical; 
        System.Drawing.RectangleF rect = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, 1000, 200); 
        CharacterRange[] ranges = { new System.Drawing.CharacterRange(0, text.Length) }; 
        System.Drawing.Region[] regions = new System.Drawing.Region[1]; 

        format.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(ranges); 

        regions = graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, rect, format); 
        rect = regions[0].GetBounds(graphics); 

        return rect; 
    }
```

If I give this several lines of text to measure in a font that supports CJK, I get dramatically different results in Mono than in Windows 10. In Mono I get a much different box that only seems to be as wide as a single line of text.

Are some of the flags like StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical not supported? Is there a plan to support them in the future?

Comment: on which platform are you executing your code? mono itself very likely is not to blame here. Just like Microsoft.NET, it will call into GDIPlus.dll for `MeasureCharacterRanges`, and the ports of that library to X11 or Carbon or Cocoa may do stuff not the same way as Windows does.

Comment: ok we really need to know which platform, components and versions you have. the [current libgdiplus source](https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/blob/master/src/text-cairo.c#L830) handles `DirectionVertical`, on top of the cairo graphics library.

Comment: I am running mono on Ubuntu Linux (4.10.0-33-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu).

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 5.2.0.215 (tarball Mon Aug 14 15:46:23 UTC 2017)
libgdiplus.so.0.0.0, Dated Dec 2015 (BuildID[sha1]=9f1c72bdfe50a32cb144d8c7f4414e21d8e6eb3c)

Comment: libgdiplus is already the newest version (4.2-1ubuntu1)

Comment: The only thing I can offer would be an attempt to reproduce. I have several libraries in use that deal with glyph placement in combination with Unicode fonts, also CJK. please add the font specification, and a sample text input.

Comment: Text is 鵠蕾北にっらぬ逼りのなかに櫛麗遣りがぁる。東西に走る四条通りを當って寮から漂ヘとっっ<” 曹琶もなれほ、鰹ゃ人並みで萱ないほとにきわう中心地ヅ。るその虫扁蜻を北へ行って西に少し入ゝ ヵって突能尖校こ出る。 本能寺の葦'」建てられたが、、 ま扇糟なつている。 そこを通るたぴに思
Font is [Font: Name=DejaVu Sans, Size=9, Units=3, GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]
text length is 138
Rect is {X=0,Y=0,Width=13,Height=203}

Comment: confirmed to be reproducable. 
Windows 10: {X = 878 Y = 0 Width = 122 Height = 200}
Ubuntu: {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 13 Height = 203}
I also did a DrawString() with the same font, layout rectangle and format used for measurecharacterranges, and on Ubuntu it is cropped and starting in the top left corner, while on Windows 10, it is aligned with the right border of the layout rectangle, making for a nice *tategaki*. my thoughts go in the direction of either RTL, or Jap. syllable breaking rules, or both, handled improperly.
don't know if @Sebastien Pouliot is on SO for an expert opinion.